# Understanding last step of a proof that "two trajectories cannot cross at a finite value of t" (Phase trajectories/nodes)

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Note: This proof prefaced critical points at the origin for coupled first order ODEs. It was done before showing the asymptotically stable and unstable critical points: Improper, Proper, Spiral, Center, Saddle and Degenerate.

I have read that two trajectories cannot cross at a finite value of $t$(Phase plane and nodes). The following proof was attached:

> Proof: Suppose $\vec y_A(t_A) = \vec y_{P_0} = \vec y_B (t_B)$
>
> Set $\vec y(t) = \vec y_A (t + t_A) - \vec y_B (t+t_B)$
>
> $\Rightarrow \vec y'(t) = A \vec y(t), \vec y(0) = \vec 0$
>
> Clearly $\vec y(t) = \vec 0$ is a solution to these equations, so uniqueness implies $\vec y(t) = \vec 0$, therefore $\vec y_A (t+t_A) = \vec y_B (t+t_b) \Rightarrow traj_A ,traj_B$ are the same **near $P_0$ - but do not cross.**

That is how it is written. Now I believe I am following everything correctly, but I am not sure how they reached that conclusion (in bold). Are they saying that they can't even touch? Or merely that they can't pass through each other?

(Sorry about the tags, I can't read them because the tag descriptions are mostly off the screen for some reason)

> Perhaps they are saying the critical point at $t= - \infty$ is the only point where two trajectories touch, and outside of that they immediately diverge, and hence they are only every close outside of this point.

Note: I do understand that this is true. I am only confused by this proof.

Comment: After reading the above several times, I am only confused too by this proof )-:

Comment: Where does the conclusion $\Rightarrow \vec y'(t) = A \vec y(t)$ come from?  What is $A$?  There must have been some context or assumptions about the structure of $\vec y_A(t)$ and $\vec y_B(t)$.  Any result that two trajectories cannot cross must be speaking about some particular type of trajectory -- can you tell us what definition of "trajectory" is being used?

Comment: @Matt $A$ here is a matrix of values that are used to create coupled systems of first order ODE's.

$y_1' = \alpha y_1 + \beta y_2$
$y_2' = \gamma y_1 + \delta y_2$

from $\vec{y'} = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{pmatrix} \vec{y}$

Sorry, I should have been more clear. This is trajectories of phase plane analysis(I have just started).

Comment: @Rahul I wanted that part of the text in the title in italics, hence the Latex text rendering, I am currently using a tablet pc that has specs likely lower than almost any other user on M.SE, so I doubt the rendering was delaying anyone, is there any other reason to remove the code?

Comment: [Guidelines for good use of LaTeX in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles/9730#9730)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Only the last thing there was relevant: 

" It does not look nice in plaintext fields like the 'hot questions' list or users' notifications, and ultimately it is superfluous."

That is entirely subjective. "Always respect the original author." - http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/793/editing-responses-that-have-perceived-errors

The only actual concern is in regards to those with very slow processing rates, I can guarantee that I am an accurate representative for this group, and I can say it isn't an issue.

Note: 
Vertical height was unchanged.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Also, on an unrelated note, on your website. The link here for: "Michal Takács: Hadamardove matice, B.Sc. Thesis 2009" is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting the story as follows: We are given the system of linear ODEs
$$y'=Ay, \qquad A:=\left[\matrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}\right]$$
in ${\mathbb R}^2$. Assume that we have two trajectories
$$y_P:\ t\mapsto y_P(t), \quad y_P(0)=P;\qquad y_Q:\ t\mapsto y_Q(t), \quad y_Q(0)=Q$$
with initial points $P$, $Q\in{\mathbb R}^2$, found by whichever means, and assume that these trajectories have a common point $Y\in{\mathbb R}^2$. This means that there are finite $t$-values $t_P$ and $t_Q$ with
$$y_P(t_P)=y_Q(t_Q)=Y\ .$$
It is claimed that in such a situation one has
$$y_Q(t)=y_P(t-t_P+t_Q)\qquad(-\infty<t<\infty)\ ,\tag{1}$$
i.e., that the two trajectories differ just by a shift of the time scale.
In order to prove $(1)$ one considers the auxiliary function
$$\tau\mapsto z(\tau):=y_P(t_P+\tau)-y_Q(t_Q+\tau)\ .$$
This function can be viewed as the uniquely determined solution of the initial problem
$$z'=Az,\quad z(0)=0\ .$$
It follows that $z(\tau)\equiv0$, first in a suitable neighborhood of $\tau=0$, and then in all of ${\mathbb R}$. For the latter a certain "local to global" argument is needed, which is proven in the general theory of ODEs.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, I will just absorb it now and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks you, yes this clears it up! Very nice answer!